# Deadlink (404) editing post

Tags: discussion, editing

If question or answered post have included dead(404) link and we update that  with current working link for example in magento github repo in version 2.0 there is develop branch currently not so. that type of link should be editable..

Can user edit that post or not.

If editable then why community members are rejecting that edit ?

Here is the screenshot i have edited post with working link
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can user edit that post or not.**

*yes, you can edit those dead(404) links* .

> If editable then why community members are rejecting that edit?

If any community member rejects then they did the mistake.

Please share the edit links where your edit is got the reject,We moderator check those Post.

> Also, request to all community member, Please do a proper  check
>   before Reject any edit.
>
> As a community member, we should have do a proper check on all edits and
>   reviews before taking any action.

Himanshu, we encourage your contributions over those 404 link.!:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...

Comment: Here is the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/144563

Comment: this is also https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/144519